# JComboBox ActionListener not working after removeAllItems() was used

Tags: java, actionlistener, jcombobox, removeall

I have two JComboBoxes; one removes all items in the other if it's already populated and then adds a new set of items, and the second fires an event that gets information from a database using the selected item. The problem occurs after the first combo box does its thing removing the items and adding new ones; when I select any of the items in the second JComboBox, the event that fires doesn't happen anymore.

Below I have provided snippets of my code:

The first combo box

```
    cmbIDs.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            selection = (String)cmbIDs.getSelectedItem();
            if (!(selection.equals("Select an username")))//current selection in combobox is stored as string
            {
                comboActivate(selection);
                if (!unitC.getText().equals("")){
                    unitC.setText("");
                }
                if (!lecturer.getText().equals("")){
                    lecturer.setText("");
                }

                if (!(courseD.getText().equals("Not Enrolled"))){    
                    populateUnits(selection);
                }

            }
            else{
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Please select a Surname.");
            }
        }
    });
```

Removing the items inside populateUnits(String selectionID):

```
    try 
    {
        units.removeAllItems();
        units.addItem("Select a Unit");
    }
    catch (NullPointerException npe)
    {
        units.addItem("Select a Unit"); 
    }
```

After this instructions are sent through a client to a server where a db is queried and the server replies with information which is then added to the second JComboBox. I assure you also that the items are added to the JComboBox after removeAllItems() is used.

The second jComboBox:

```
units.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ue)
    {
        uSelect = (String)units.getSelectedItem();
        if (!(uSelect.equals("Select a Unit")))//current selection in combobox is stored as string
        {
            System.out.println(uSelect);
            unitActivate(uSelect);
        }
        else
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Please select a Unit.");
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Please format your code so it is readable

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your code never gets a fresh set of items from the database, so the user can never select anything other than "Select an Unit", which your second code block ignores.

Comment: The method add items to the second jcombo box is done after an item in the first JComboBox is selected. i just didnt add the code to my question which i shall try to do so now.

Comment: Where is the actionListener being added? Are you calling addActionListener() every time you refresh the data in units?

Comment: nope its called outside the method where the data is refreshed. i tried calling the method where the data was refreshed but it made no difference.

Comment: update- before i kept the actionlistener outside the method when i was calling it also in the refresh data method. I just trieditonly in the method and now the actionlistener is finally doing something. It doesnt seem to be fully workin. ill update again in a sec

Comment: Ok so the action listener only works on the first refresh and doesnt afterwards. i thinkmaybe i should also remove the action listener whhen i use removeallitems then add it again after the datas refreshed.

Answer (score 0):

it work for me

```
try {
     boxListMaterial.removeActionListener(controller);
     boxListMaterial.removeAllItems();
}catch (Exception e){}
boxListMaterial.addActionListener(controller);
```

Controller - ActionListener*